# Visualizing PNDs in Petrov classification of Weyl Curvature

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, curvature, spinors

In 3+1 dimensional space-times, we can decompose Weyl curvature as $D(2,0)$ and $D(0,2)$ irreducible representations of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Further, if such space-time admits spin-bundle, we can map these irreducible representations of Weyl curvature to symmetric 4 indexed spinors $\Psi_{ABCD}$ (and its complex conjugate) called gravitational spinors. Since $\Psi_{ABCD}$ is  symmetric, it is possible to show that there exist 2-spinors $\alpha^A, \beta^B, \gamma^C, \delta^D$ such that $\Psi_{ABCD}$ can be written as symmetrization over tensor product of these four spinors: $$\Psi_{ABCD}=\alpha_{(A}\beta_B\gamma_C\delta_{D)}$$ Petrov classification refers to the classification scheme of gravitational spinor $\Psi_{ABCD}$, which is done based on the   degeneracy of principle null directions (PND's) represented by the four spinors $\alpha_A, \beta_B, \gamma_C, \delta_D$. Given an orthonormal spin frame $(o_A,\iota^A)$, we can construct five scalar functions, called Weyl scalars, simply by contracting $\Psi_{ABCD}$ with the $o's$ and $\iota's$. By looking at which of these scalars vanish, we can deduce the Petrov class of the given curvature spinor $\Psi_{ABCD}$.

Now, if we consider Schwarzschild geometry for instance, we see that it possess Type D Weyl curvature, thus two non-degenerate null directions. How does these two directions emerge in an otherwise spherically symmetric space-time ? Since Schwarzschild is vacuum solution, the two PNDs of the Weyl curvature constitutes shear free rays. This leads me to suspect that the PNDS are defined with respect to shear free null congruence (for vacuum solutions only). In general what does these null directions physically represent? And, is there a way to visualize each of these PNDS?